# mongorestore from mongodump fails

Tags: mongodb

Perhaps it's because there's a conflict between the data from MongoDB version 2.6 and version 2.4, but here's the problem.

```
$ ./scripts/mongo/mongo-restore-local.sh "$HOME/mongodump_dev"
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    preparing collections to restore from
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/WiredTiger", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/WiredTiger.lock", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/WiredTiger.turtle", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/WiredTiger.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/WiredTigerLAS.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/_mdb_catalog.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/WiredTiger", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/WiredTiger.lock", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/WiredTiger.turtle", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/WiredTiger.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/WiredTigerLAS.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/_mdb_catalog.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/collection-0-393995361810699373.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/collection-2-393995361810699373.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with subdirectory "cdt_db/diagnostic.data", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/index-1-393995361810699373.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/index-3-393995361810699373.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/index-4-393995361810699373.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with subdirectory "cdt_db/journal", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.425-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/mongod.lock", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.426-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/cdt_db/sizeStorer.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.426-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/collection-0-1615163121329617102.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.426-0700    don't know what to do with file "/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/collection-2-1615163121329617102.wt", skipping...
2017-09-26T18:08:48.426-0700    Failed: error scanning filesystem: invalid database name 'diagnostic.data': illegal character '.' found in db name 'diagnostic.data'
```

The script that ran the above is as follows:

```
mongorestore "$1" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

The "$HOME/mongodump_dev" directory was filled with mongo data by running a mongodump command.

Does anyone know why I am getting that error

```
2017-09-26T18:08:48.426-0700    Failed: error scanning filesystem: invalid database name 'diagnostic.data': illegal character '.' found in db name 'diagnostic.data'
```

Is it a mongodb version 2.6/2.4 conflict?

Comment: if you did a mongodump with 2 and a mongorestore with 3 - that might be the problem, yes

Comment: Ok so the data was generated with Mongo version 2.4, could that data possibly conflct with Mongo version 2.6? seems unlikely...but that's the only disparity remaining.

Comment: I see WiredTiger files in the dump. Did you use WiredTiger engine with 2.4?

Comment: Have you've been running a mongod instance using '/Users/alexamil/mongodump_dev/' as dbPath? Dumping your data to a different directory should solve the errors when running mongorestore in that case.